# Continuous function $f: [0,1]\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ such that $\int_0^x f(t) dt \geq f(x) \forall x\in [0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Question is to check for :

Existence of a Continuous function $f: [0,1]\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ such that :

$$\int_0^x f(t) dt \geq f(x) \forall x\in [0,1]$$

Now, first thing i noticed is that i can check for polynomials first..

because every continuous function on $[0,1]$ is approximated by polynomials.

suppose $f(x)=1$ then I would have $\int_0^x f(t) dt =x\ngeq f(x)=1\forall x\in [0,1]$ as $0\leq x\leq1$

Suppose $f(x)=x$ then I would have $\int_0^x f(t) dt=\frac{x^2}{2}\ngeq f(x)=x\forall x\in [0,1]$ as $x\leq 1$

So, I am not getting proper outcome if i proceed in this way....

I some how feel $f(x)=0$ is the only function which satisfies this property.

I would be thankful if some one can help me out...

Thank you :)

EDIT :

I tried all standard functions :

$f(x)=e^x \Rightarrow \int_0^x e^t dt =e^x-1\ngeq e^x$  So, this fails.

$f(x)=\sin x \Rightarrow \int_0^x \sin t dt = 1-\cos x \ngeq \sin x $ So, this fails.

$f(x)=\cos x \Rightarrow \int_0^x \cos t dt = \sin x \ngeq \cos x $ So, this fails.

Comment: Hint: try something that grows faster than any polynomial.

Comment: $e^x$? I tried that, but $\int_0^x e^t dt =e^x-1\ngeq e^x$.... :(

Comment: Never mind, I was hallucinating.

Comment: So, what do you suggest me to go for :(

Comment: This is a simple case of a more general result : the Gronwall's inequality.

Comment: @user37238 : Would you please try to make your comment as an answer...

Comment: My answer would be Ewan Delanoy's one. The proof of the Gronwall's inequality is quite similar to the proof of Ewan Delanoy.

Comment: fine fine.. Thank you for your interest... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no nonzero solution. If we put 
$F(x)=\int_{0}^x f(t)dt$, we have $F(0)=0$ and $F'(x)=f(x)$. Next,
put $G(x)=F(x)e^{-x}$. Then $G'(x)=(F'(x)-F(x))e^{-x} \leq 0$, so
$G$ is decreasing. Since $G(0)=0$, $G$ is nonpositive, and $F$ also.
Since $f$ and $F$ are also nonnegative, this forces $f=0$.

Comment: Ok ok... This is hitting some thing but i am not sure if i understood totally... Please give me two minutes i will ask if there is any problem.. Thank you..

Comment: I guess i got it... Not very sure... Could you please add more details where ever you feel necessary..

Comment: Perhaps my method will look more natural to you if you reflect that your problem is a “differential inequation”.

Comment: I guess you are right.. But i could not do that :(

Comment: You know about the theory of linear differential equations ? For differential INequations, you apply the same methods with a twist.

Comment: Ok.. I would try :) Thank you