# Continuous non-negative function with $f(x) \leq \int_{0}^{x} f(t) \,dt$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Let $f$ be continuous non-negative on $[0, 1]$ with $f(x) \leq \int_{0}^{x} f(t) \,dt \space \forall x \in (0,1].$

Is it true that $\forall x \in [0,1], f(x)=0$?

Comment: Check out the integral form of Gronwall's inequality! (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality)

Comment: Asked and answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/602535/42969 and here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2490632/42969 and here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2052573/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24f(x)%20%5Cleq%20%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7Bx%7D%20f(t)%20%5C%2Cdt%24)

Comment: This one is a little different since the property that $f(x) < $ the given integral only holds for $x \in (0,1].$ I had a hard time finding what f(0) is. Once I get that I think I could do the rest.

Comment: @LTM $F(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(t) \,dt$ is continuous. As $h \to +0$, $0 \leq f(h) \leq F(h) \to F(0) = 0$, which means $f(h) \to 0$.

Comment: So more formally, since f is non-neg on $[0,1], $ $0 \leq f(x).$ And for $x \in (0,1] 0 \leq f(x) \leq \int_{0}^{x} f(t) \, dt.$ And $\lim_{x \to 0+} \int_{0}^{x} f(t) \, dt = \lim_{x \to 0+} F(x)-F(0) = 0.$ Then as $x \to 0+ $ we have $0 \leq f(x) \leq 0$ which means $f(0)=0$